# How to rescue timeout issues (Ruby, Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

most of my apps have a lot to do with web services and often due to the third party site, I get timeout issues.

This is the error that I get:

```
  execution expired
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:54:in `rbuf_fill'
```

How do I rescue this kind of error in a rails app?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Depending on how you use the library, there are different ways to rescue the exception.

**In the library**

Assuming you created a wrapper to access some kind of web service, you can have the wrapper rescue the exception and always return a "safe" data.

**In the action**

If you call a specific method in the action and the method success is a requirement for the action, then you can rescue it in the action.
In the following example I rescue the error and show a specific template to handle the problem.

```
def action
  perform_external_call
rescue Timeout::Error => e
  @error = e
  render :action => "error"
end
```

**In the controller**

If the method call can occur in many different actions, you might want to use `rescue_from`.

```
class TheController < ApplicationController

  rescue_from Timeout::Error, :with => :rescue_from_timeout

  protected

  def rescue_from_timeout(exception)
    # code to handle the issue
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the awesome [Rack::Timeout](https://github.com/kch/rack-timeout) gem for your rack apps

Then use Simone's controller goodness

Answer (score 2):

this is what I do in my rails apps:

```
# in ApplicationController
rescue_from Your::Exception, :with => :handle_exception

protected

def handle_exception
  # do anything you want here
end
```

You may specify the exception like you would do in a rescue clause of course.

Greetings,
Joe

Comment: Never rescue `Exception`. Is a bad programming habit. You should rescue specific exceptions or at least, `StandardError`.

Comment: "Exception" was meant to clarify where to catch the specific one, but you're right, this should have been clearer! :)

Comment: I kinda knew how to do this with ActiveRecord not found. I just didn't know what or how to rescue that particular error.

Comment: If you don't want ActiveRecord to blow up on you, try Object.find_by_key(params[:id])
This will return a null object you can work with without all the ugly exception handling code.