# How to tell a connect timeout error from a read timeout error in Ruby's Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby

My question is related to [How to rescue timeout issues (Ruby, Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370140/how-to-rescue-timeout-issues-ruby-rails).

Here's the common way to rescue from a timeout:

```
def action
  # Post using Net::HTTP
rescue Timeout::Error => e
  # Do something
end
```

I'd like to determine if the exception was raised while trying to **connect** to the host, or if it was raised while trying to **read** from the host. Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the solution (after Ben's fix):

```
require "net/http"
http = Net::HTTP.new("example.com")
http.open_timeout = 2
http.read_timeout = 3
begin
  http.start
  begin
    http.request_get("/whatever?") do |res|
      res.read_body
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
    puts "Timeout due to reading"
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts "Timeout due to connecting"
end
```

Comment: Marc, I really want this to be true, but it's not working for me. I think it's because `http.request_get` creates and uses a new instance of `Net::HTTP` that doesn't inherit the timeout variables.

Comment: I take that back, it doesn't create a new instance of `Net:HTTP`. Still, it seems to timeout around 30 seconds no matter what I set the open and read timeouts to.

Comment: open_timeout works for me, on both ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 dev. It's harder to test read_timeout, and it might be per block read, you should check the code. Still, if you put both to 0.1, it should timeout quickly, no?

In any case, my answer is still the valid way to distinguish what caused the timeout!

Comment: Figured it out. I was testing with "blah.com", which has no DNS entry. The code above doesn't catch a timeout due to resolution failure for some reason. Your code works perfectly with a small modification. You have to put `request_get` inside the inner rescue block, and add a call to `http.start` in the outer rescue block, like this: http://gist.github.com/364868

Update your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks so much Marc!

Comment: Ah, good, and sorry for not getting it quite right. I updated the answer with your modification.

Answer (score 2):

Marc-André Lafortune's solution is still the best if you can't upgrade to ruby 2.x.

Starting from 2.x, a subclass of `Timeout::Error` will be raised depending on which timeout was triggered:

- `Net::OpenTimeout`
- `Net::ReadTimeout`

However, the `read_timeout` behavior is strange on 2.x, because it seems to double the value you set. [This article](https://engineering.wework.com/ruby-users-be-wary-of-net-http-f284747288b2) explains why.

Here's a test for both timeouts (tested on 1.8.7, 1.9.3, 2.1.2, 2.2.4).

EDIT: The open_timeout test works on Mac, but on Linux, the client gets a "connection refused" error.

```
require "net/http"
require "socket"

SERVER_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_PORT = 9999

def main
  puts 'with_nonlistening_server'
  with_nonlistening_server do
    make_request
  end
  
  puts
  puts 'with_listening_server'
  with_listening_server do
    make_request
  end
end

def with_listening_server
  # This automatically starts listening
  serv = TCPServer.new(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT)
  begin
    yield
  ensure
    serv.close
  end
end

def with_nonlistening_server
  raw_serv = Socket.new Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0
  addr     = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in SERVER_PORT, SERVER_HOST

  # Bind, but don't listen
  raw_serv.bind addr
  begin
    yield
  ensure
    raw_serv.close
  end
end

def make_request
  http = Net::HTTP.new(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT)
  http.open_timeout = 1
  http.read_timeout = 1  # seems to be doubled on ruby 2.x
  start_tm = Time.now
  begin
    http.start
    begin
      http.get('/')
    rescue Timeout::Error => err
      puts "Read timeout: #{err.inspect}"
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error => err
    puts "Open timeout: #{err.inspect}"
  end
  end_tm = Time.now
  puts "Duration (sec): #{end_tm - start_tm}"
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  main
end
```

Example output on 1.9.3:

```
with_nonlistening_server
Open timeout: #<Timeout::Error: execution expired>
Duration (sec): 1.002477

with_listening_server
Read timeout: #<Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error>
Duration (sec): 1.00599
```

Example output on 2.1.2:

```
with_nonlistening_server
Open timeout: #<Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired>
Duration (sec): 1.005923

with_listening_server
Read timeout: #<Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout>
Duration (sec): 2.009582
```